# How to get all values in a certain column with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to print out all the usernames of my members in my site as a list, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to use 'mysqli_fetch_array' function to fetch names from username column, but I've been failing. So, please assist me on how I can do this in a most efficient way.

This is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
$array = Array;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $array =  row[];
}
foreach ($names as $array) {
     echo $names;
}
```

Also I want to format the output, like separating each username by " | "

Comment: `$array = Array;` is flat out wrong. that should be `$array = Array();` or just `$array = [];` on newer PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close..

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['username'].'|';
}
```

Comment: what if two rows has the matching data and I would like to echo only one to represent both rows –

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, "Array" should be "array()" and you're doubling up, by assigning array values into an array, results are returned in an array already. Code below should work...

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($query));

foreach ($array as $name) {
    echo $name["username"] . "|";
}
```

Looks like you also had your foreach loop round the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

no need to use extra `foreach`, just do this way-

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo $row["username"] . "|";
}
```

Comment: what if two rows has the matching data and I would like to echo only one to represent both rows

Answer (score 0):

**Don't worry it is really very easy**

```
<?php
//All your preceding code 
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
?>
<ul>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo "<li>" . $row['username'] . "</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if two rows has the matching data and I would like to echo only one to represent both rows